# SQLAlchemy Upsert unable to find table "excluded"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, upsert

Disclaimer: I recently took over someone else's codebase so some of the code you see here was already premade. I've also changed certain variable names to more generic code names that probably wouldn't actually work.

I am trying to bulk upsert on a postgres DB using SQLAlchemy but am having trouble. It seems that when SQLAlchemy goes to access the data it needs to update the table (excluded.columnName) It is unable to be found.

First here is the error I'm getting:

```
    Missing FROM-clause entry for table "excluded"
    LINE 1: ...tablename) VALUES (excluded.tablename...
```

And my code:

```
    index_fields = list(billocity_db.get_indexes(self.table_name))
    for row in self.data:
        if 'id' in self.column_info.keys():
            del row['id']
        data = row.to_dict()
        insert_stmt = insert(self.table).values(data)
        for i in index_fields:
            if i in data:
                del data[i]
        for key in data.keys():
            data[key] = insert_stmt.excluded[key]
            print(data[key])
        print(data)
        insert_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
            #Tried both constraint and index_elements with same result
            #constraint=self.table_name,
            #None of my columns are 'id'. Could that be an issue?
            index_elements=['id'],
            set_=data
        )
        try:
            print(insert_stmt)
            self.session.execute(insert_stmt)
        except Exception as e:
            self.session.rollback()
            self.log.exception(str(e))
        finally:
            self.session.commit()
```

The error comes immediately after calling

```
self.session.execute(insert_stmt)
```

And this is what insert_stmt prints as right before execute, obviously column_name and table_name is just place holder.

```
 INSERT INTO
 table_name (column_name, column_name, column_name, 
 column_name, column_name, column_name, column_name, 
 column_name, column_name, column_name, column_name, 
 column_name, column_name, column_name, column_name, 
 column_name) 
 VALUES
    (
 excluded.column_name, excluded.column_name, excluded.column_name, 
 excluded.column_name, excluded.column_name, excluded.column_name, 
 excluded.column_name, excluded.column_name, excluded.column_name, 
 excluded.column_name, excluded.column_name, excluded.column_name, 
 excluded.column_name, excluded.column_name, excluded.column_name, 
 excluded.column_name
 )
 ON CONFLICT (id) DO 
 UPDATE SET
 column_name= excluded.column_name, column_name= excluded.column_name, 
 column_name= excluded.column_name, column_name= excluded.column_name, 
 column_name= excluded.column_name, column_name= excluded.column_name, 
 column_name= excluded.column_name, column_name= excluded.column_name, 
 column_name= excluded.column_name, column_name= excluded.column_name, 
 column_name= excluded.column_name, column_name= excluded.column_name, 
 column_name= excluded.column_name, column_name= excluded.column_name, 
 column_name= excluded.column_name, column_name= excluded.column_name 
 RETURNING 
 table_name.id
```

I can't find many extra resources online about this issue and I have no idea what else to try. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`EXCLUDED` is available in the `UPDATE` section, but not in the `VALUES` section.

This is [a good tutorial about UPSERT](https://www.depesz.com/2015/05/10/waiting-for-9-5-add-support-for-insert-on-conflict-do-nothingupdate/)

And there's always the official docs for [INSERT ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)